# CSS Grid 2 columns and 1 row, H1 creates new row

Tags: css, css-grid

I am using CSS grid for a website, and in the information section I have 2 columns:
on the left a paragraph with information, on the right the image.

However, when I want to add an h1 to the paragraph it creates an extra column, resulting in:
On the left the header, on the right the image and underneath the header is now the paragraph.

I've now avoided the problem by using  and making a class for the first sentence of the paragraph (making that  sentence look like a h1) but it feels like a makeshift solution. Is there a better way to solve this problem?
I've tried 2fr 2fr, still the same problem
[I've added a screenshot of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdxBT.jpg)
(I'm still very new to CSS grid)

```
.block1{
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr; 
    column-gap: 250px;
    background-color: #EFEDE3;
    padding: 150px;

 
  }
  .block1 img{
    justify-self: end;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 75%;
  }
  .block1 span {
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 32px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

HTML:

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="paragraph">
        <h1>Paragraph</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="imageBox">
        
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr;
  column-gap: 250px;
}

.paragraph {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 40vh;
}

.imageBox {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 40vh;
}
```

Comment: I didn't have a class for my paragraph and creating that has fixed the problem. Thank you very much!